# Becoming Expat in Vietnam, How do people retire in Vietnam? What paperwork do I need to be able to live permanently?

Tags: visa, residency

I am planning to temporarily retire in South Eastern Asia, (with my family - wife 2 kids) for a year or two. I am planning to live for about half of year in each Thailand, Cambodia, Laos and Vietnam, to try them out and see where I fit in best and then possibly settle in the one we feel is best for us. I am planning to start with Vietnam.

**EDIT:**  I would have around 1k EUR of passive income per month, no plans to work, citizenship is EU (Lithuania), no plans to change citizenship.

**How do people retire in Vietnam? What paperwork do I need to be able to live permanently?**

Comment: Citizenship? Planning to work at all? Do you have a decent amount of income/savings?

Comment: @mkennedy I would have around 1k EUR of passive income, no plans to work, citizenship is EU (Lithuania).